# Sharp corners in RFID antennas

Tags: antenna, rfid, pcb-antenna

I have heard anecdotally that a square HF RFID antenna performs worse than a circular one, but I am struggling to find any articles on why this is the case.

I assume there is a charge concentration at a sharp corner, as electric charges accumulate at sharp points. Is the result similar to the Skin effect, in that it artificially increases resistance, making the antenna more lossy? If so, is there a way to calculate the impact of this? I can calculate the increase in resistance due to the skin effect (which can be significant in RFID antenna design), so it seems like it should be possible to calculate the effect of this too, but none of the papers I have read on the topic of HF antennas cover this.

There seem to be a lot of RFID tags which are rectangular, with the corners being rounded with a fairly small bend radius (i.e. not far from a right angle).

Comment: The angle of the bend of the corner isn't what's important. Those rounded corners you see have the trace width stay constant. Sharp corners mean that the trace width of any perpendicular cross section wouldn't be the same (at a sharp 90 degree corner you'd have x*sqrt(2) width versus width x of the trace). Variation in cross section make for a bad antenna (it would lower the Q of that inductor tuning for each corner, compounding errors). Charge accumulation would be more of a side effect and not as detrimental as the variation in the antenna dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

RFID "antennas" are really just induction coils (unless you're talking about UHF tags).

As such, their performance is almost entirely determined by the area inside the loop, and a rectangular loop is the best way to maximize the area if you're constrained to a rectangular tag.

The rounded corners are simply to prevent excessive concentration of stress in the wire during the manufacturing process.

It is true that in the absence of any other constraints, a circular loop will give you the maximum area for a given length of wire, but this aspect is usually overridden by unrelated requirements.

Comment: Area inside the loop is important, but there are definitely other factors. The Q of the coil (i.e. how lossy it is) has a very definite impact on read range. Does the shape of the trace not affect this loss in any way then? Loss can be calculated purely from the skin effect equation?